# Pandas data frame to Table in Word doc using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datatable, python-docx

I am inserting the pandas data frame as a table in a Word document using Python. I am using docx library but somehow while running a loop that creates three data frames it updates the same values in all of them, can you please let me know what's missing here?

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

data1 = {'Header':['L1','L2','L3'], 'Val1':[float(100),float(200),float(300)],
         'Val2':[float(400),float(500),float(600)], 'Val3': 
         [float(700),float(800),float(900)]}
data1_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

# Inside loop it'll create two more such outputs but with different values but with the same labels.

data2 = {'Header':['L5','L6'], 'Val5':[float(1000),float(1100)],
         'Val6':[float(1300),float(1400)]}
data2_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

data3 = {'Header':['L7','L8','L9','L10'], 'Val7':[float(1900),float(2000),float(2100),float(2200)],
         'Val8':[float(2900),float(2300),float(2400),float(2800)], 'Val9': 
         [float(3500),float(3600),float(3700),float(3900)]}
data3_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data3)

# Here are the two functions that help to add the table.

def make_rows_bold(row):
    """
    This function sets all the cells in the 'row' to bold. 
    To be used to set the header row to bold.
    """
    for cell in row.cells:
        for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                run.font.bold = True

def add_table_to_word_doc(input_df: pd.DataFrame, document):
    """
    This function converts the the input_df into a table, adds it to the input document, and then returns the document.
    """
    # this create a table of the size of the df
    table = document.add_table(input_df.shape[0]+1, input_df.shape[1])
    
    # convert the column names of the dataframe to column titles of the ms word table
    for col in range(input_df.shape[-1]):
        table.cell(0, col).text = input_df.columns[col]

    # add the rest of the dataframe to the table
    for row in range(input_df.shape[0]):
        for col in range(input_df.shape[-1]):
            table.cell(row+1, col).text = str(input_df.values[row, col])
    
    # style of the table ('Table Grid' is just the normal table)
    table.style = 'Table Grid'
    
    # set the title row to bold
    make_rows_bold(table.rows[0])

    return document
```

Comment: What do you mean by "updates the same values in all of them"? - are you referring to resulting word document tables?

Comment: @Milan Yes, the resulting word document have same values for all three tables. I suspect this could be because every time in loop, the function just populate last value.

Comment: why not put the solution here?